# PySpark write parquet from directory partitionned by file name

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

In HDFS, i have a folder `/landing/my_data/flow_name/` within this folder i have bunch of `.csv` files :

- /landing/my_data/children_flow/20212503_1_children.csv
- /landing/my_data/children_flow/20212503_2_children.csv
- /landing/my_data/children_flow/20212503_3_children.csv

I want to create a parquet file partitioned by the files name using the `/landing/my_data/children_flow/` directory and put it into `/staging/my_data/children_flow/`.

I want `/staging/my_data/children_flow/` to look like this :

- /staging/my_data/children_flow/file_name=20212503_1_children/*.parquet
- /staging/my_data/children_flow/file_name=20212503_2_children/*.parquet
- /staging/my_data/children_flow/file_name=20212503_3_children/*.parquet

I thought about reading every file from `/landing/my_data/children_flow` into a DataFrame, then adding the file name as a column and finally creating my parquet file which will be partitioned by the `file_name` column.

```
children_files = hdfs.list("/landing/my_data/children_flow/")
df = spark.read.csv(os.path.join("/landing/my_data/children_flow/", children_files[0]))
df = df.withColumn("file_name", lit(children_files[0].replace(".csv", "")))
children_files.pop(0)
for one_file in children_files :
    df2 = spark.read.csv(os.path.join("/landing/my_data/children_flow/", one_file))
    df2 = df2.withColumn("file_name", lit(one_file.replace(".csv", "")))
    df = df.union(df2)
df.write.partitionBy("file_name").parquet("/staging/my_data/children_flow/")
```

But im not sure that is the best solution...Anyone can help me up with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this :

```
children_files = hdfs.list("/landing/my_data/children_flow/")
df = spark.createDataFrame(
            spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD(),
            dfSchema
)
df = df.withColumn("file_name", lit(None))
for one_file in children_files :
    df2 = spark.read.csv(os.path.join("/landing/my_data/children_flow/", one_file))
    df2 = df2.withColumn("file_name", lit(one_file.replace(".csv", "")))
    df = df.union(df2)
df.write.partitionBy("file_name").parquet("/staging/my_data/children_flow/")
```

I feel like its better to use a `emptyRDD()`.